# Scrollable areas in a fixed flex box layout

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a fixed (position: fixed) 2-column layout; the second column (yellow in the example) should be allowed to scroll independently of the first and the first has a nested flexbox of 3 rows, the third of which should be independently scrollable (red in the example).

I've tried setting the overflow of these divs but it seems to be ignored and the content cannot be scrolled.

Please see the example below and the attached jsFiddle.

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-flow: column nowrap; justify-content: flex-start; align-content: stretch; align-items: stretch; position: fixed; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; left: 0px;">


<div style="order: 0; align-self: auto; flex: 0 1 3em;">
    <div style="background: orange;">Announcements</div>
  </div>
  <div style="order: 0; align-self: auto; flex: 1 1 auto;">
    <div style="display: flex; flex-flow: row nowrap; justify-content: flex-start; align-content: stretch; align-items: stretch;">
      <div style="order: 0; align-self: auto; flex: 1 1 auto;">
        <div style="display: flex; flex-flow: column nowrap; justify-content: flex-start; align-content: stretch; align-items: stretch;">
          <div style="order: 0; align-self: auto; flex: 0 1 2em;">
            <div style="background: rgb(139, 139, 222);">Menu</div>
          </div>
          <div style="order: 0; align-self: auto; flex: 1 1 auto;">
            <div style="display: flex; flex-flow: column nowrap; justify-content: flex-start; align-content: stretch; align-items: stretch;">
              <div style="order: 0; align-self: auto; flex: 0 1 2em;">
                <div style="background: green;">SubMenu</div>
              </div>
              <div style="order: 0; align-self: auto; flex: 1 1 auto;">
                <div style="overflow: auto; background: rgb(224, 71, 71);">Content
                  <div>0</div>
                  ...
                  <div>99</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style="order: 0; align-self: auto; flex: 0 1 18em;">
        <div style="overflow: auto; background: yellow;">FilterSets
          <div>0</div>
          ...
          <div>99</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/btm5cazr/3/

Comment: instead of overflow:auto use overflow:scroll and they will become scrollable

Comment: Tried that too, doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ua9kqo29/  this is what you want right ?

Comment: really @DhavalChheda, is that scrollable or just have the scrollbar?

Comment: here's [a jsfiddle based on yours](https://jsfiddle.net/m83wbuxq/), but styles are extracted to the stylesheet, to make things easier to play with

Comment: also, [this seems to be what you're looking for](https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/)

Comment: Interestingly https://jsfiddle.net/k6Lz64Lz/1/ sort of achieves what I'm looking for, but I can't see how the above code differs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original layout has a subtle issue where child flexbox declarations (display: flex) were children of a flex item (flex: ...) rather than being defined on the same element. This means that the flexbox declaration is not itself a flex item, which breaks the layout.

The correct layout is below (with jsFiddle link)

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-flow: column nowrap; justify-content: flex-start; align-content: stretch; align-items: stretch; position: fixed; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 0;">
  <div style="order: 0; align-self: auto; flex: 0 1 3em;">
    <div style="background: orange;/* display: none; */">Announcements</div>
  </div>
  <div style="order: 0; align-self: auto; flex: 1 1 auto;display: flex; flex-flow: row nowrap; justify-content: flex-start; align-content: stretch; align-items: stretch;">
      <div style="order: 0; align-self: auto; flex: 1 1 auto;display: flex; flex-flow: column nowrap; justify-content: flex-start; align-content: stretch; align-items: stretch;">
          <div style="order: 0; align-self: auto; flex: 0 1 2em;">
            <div style="background: rgb(139, 139, 222);">Menu</div>
          </div>
          <div style="order: 0; align-self: auto; flex: 1 1 auto;display: flex; flex-flow: column nowrap; justify-content: flex-start; align-content: stretch; align-items: stretch;">
              <div style="order: 0; align-self: auto; flex: 0 1 2em;">
                <div style="background: green;">SubMenu</div>
              </div>
              <div style="order: 0; align-self: auto; flex: 1 1 auto;overflow: auto;">
                <div style="background: rgb(224, 71, 71);">Content
                  <div>0</div>
                  ...
                  <div>99</div>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div style="order: 0; align-self: auto; flex: 0 1 18em;overflow: auto;">
        <div style="background: yellow;">FilterSets
          <div>0</div>
          ...
          <div>99</div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/btm5cazr/5/